# AngularJS - Select All button not selecting all rows on table

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs

I've been working with checkboxes recently thought it would make sense to include a select all function, which can be found in my HTML and AngularJS code:

HTML:

```
 <button class="btn btn-default btn-sm" ng-click="selectChosenServices()">Select All
 </button>
```

AngularJS:

```
$scope.selectChosenServices = function () {
        for (var i = 0; i < $scope.siteUserServicesTable.data.length; i++) {
            $scope.siteUserServicesTable.data[i].chosen = true;
        }
    };
```

The code itself I've noticed does work for the current rows shown (which is set at 10), however, if I clicked to view the next page, it won't select them unless I click on the button again. I was wondering what might be the issue.

Comment: If the second page shows 10 dfiferent rows, it's normal that they aren't selected, since your code sets the first 10 to chosen = true, while you render row 11 to 20 on the second page.

Comment: Do you know anyway to resolve that issue @Shilly

Comment: can you provide html code as well for the table with pagination

Answer (score 0):

I don't know why but sometimes for loop not working proper, can you try below code ?

```
angular.forEach($scope.siteUserServicesTable, function(TableRow, Index){
 TableRow.chosen = true;
})
```

Answer (score 0):

My guess is that you are loading only 10 records at a time. And when you go to next page the next 10 records are loaded? If this is the case, it is not getting selected because while you are on the first page, you only have 10 records. The next 10 records are just not there.

Answer (score 0):

First identify that *How many records are you getting when it's render first time on page?*

- If your are getting only 10 records set each time then you have to
  call this function in initialization of each render.
- If you are getting all records then it should definitively work.
- for better performance and efficiency I would suggest you to use [lodash library](https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.10)